# How to get particular data from wp_list_comments outside the loop?

Tags: globals, comments

I need some help,very much new to wordpress.

I need only comment title and comment date from `wp_list_comments` function in my post, calling from outside loop, after declared $postid as global variable.

Now I am getting all the information about the comment such as author, date,title,comment etc. So how can I get a particular detail as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_comments` function.Pass `Post_id` as parameter.See below example

```
<?php 
$comments = get_comments('post_id=15');
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author);
endforeach;
?>
```

for more detail please check below link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

Comment: Deepa, thanks for the answer. But this is not working for me, I dont want to put default ('post_id=15'), $postid  should taken from the loop where I declared it as a global variable and I need that particular comment (title,date )outside the loop. Hope you can help me.

Comment: @Dhans Please write your code in the question.so I can help you.

Comment: Here it is....May be little horrible.....   <?php global $postid;
$postid = get_the_ID();?><!---inside the loop,declared as global variable--->

Comment: <ol class="commentlist1">
      <?php    
       //Gather comments for a specific page/post 
       $comments = get_comments(array(
        'post_id' => $postid,
        'status' => 'approve' //Change this to the type of comments to be displayed
       ));

       //Display the list of comments
       wp_list_comments(array(
        'per_page' => 8, //Allow comment pagination
        'reverse_top_level' => false, //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
        'avatar_size'       => 0
       ), $comments);

      ?>
     </ol><!--outside the loop-->

Comment: @Dhans your code is working fine at my end.Get the post_id by below code global $post; $postid=$post->ID; and pass 'ID' to 'get_comments' function.Hope it will work.

Comment: thanks, I made little modifications in other part of code, now its working. Thanks a lot..